# Corona SDK: altering the display content view

Tags: android, sdk, lua, coronasdk

Apologies if this is a common question. I have done searches, maybe i am missing the key words.

I was wondering if its possible to manipulate the x and y coordinates of the screen view? Currently the only way I know of to get off screen items to enter view is to add them all to a single display group and move them in to the view. This seems like it would be really resource intensive in a large map. Is this possible? If not is there a better practice for this sort of thing?

Comment: did you try using template for scene ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your display object in a table and use a function to change .x & .y coordinates.

```
local myGroup = { }

function drawGroup()
    local img = display.newImageRect( "baseImage.png", 100, 100 ) 
    img.x = 76
    img.y = 200
    myMap[#myMap+1] = img

    --create other items
end


function translateTo( group, x, y )
    local numItems = #myGroup
    for i=1, i < numItems, 1 do
        myGroup[i].x = myGroup[i].x + x
        myGroup[i].y = myGroup[i].y + y
    end
end

function translateTo( group, x, y, t )
    local numItems = #myGroup
    local t = t or 0
    for i=1, i < numItems, 1 do
        transition.to( myGroup[i], { time=t, x=x, y=y, delta=true} )
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a widget.newScrollView()?   This lets you have a bigger area than the screen that can scroll around for you.